# MKStoreKit 6.0 how to check auto renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I am using [MKStoreKit 6.1](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit)
I am trying to check the active subscription, here is the code:

```
- (BOOL) userHaveActiveSubscribe {
NSArray *myProductIds = @[oneMonthSubscribe, oneYearSubscribe, sixMonthSubscribe];
for (NSString *productId in myProductIds) {
    if([[MKStoreKit sharedKit] isProductPurchased:productId]) {
        if ([[MKStoreKit sharedKit] expiryDateForProduct:productId]) {
            if([[NSDate date] compare:[[MKStoreKit sharedKit] expiryDateForProduct:productId]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
                NSLog(@"USER HAVE ACTIVE SUBSCRIBE (%@)",productId);
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
}
return NO;
}
```

But I'm very worried that it might not work. I would not like to give users access if the subscription has expired, so I would not want to restrict access to them if the subscription is active.

Comment: Why do you believe that your code doesn't work? What have you tried to test if it works?

Comment: For the first time I use auto renewable subscription. When I test it, it works odd - if the subscription expired, I do the restoring of the purchase, and the subscription is again active until the next session

Comment: Hay @AntonMakerov have you get any success ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to this bug: https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/issues/270

Just ensure that the conversion to milliseconds is correctly implemented in the code